# Code analysis errors appearing as build errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: warnings, visual-studio-2019, code-analysis, build-error, .net-4.7.2

After I updated Visual Studio 2019 I am getting code analysis errors as build errors.

I couldn't find a way to move code analysis errors to warnings or disable code analysis when running build.
Other team members working on the same code base aren't facing this issue, so this must be something with Visual Studio.

Does Visual Studio 2019 has any such configuration/setting for this?

NOTE: I know disabling code analysis 'Run on build' for individual projects is one way of doing this but this is the last thing I want to do as the application has a ton of projects.

Comment: disable [code analysis in project options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#NET-Productivity)

Comment: [add this entry and set it to false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enablenetanalyzers) in a file called [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) in solution root.